# How can I write a shell.nix for a Python environment that uses a custom PyPi location?

Tags: python, nix

I have a project that includes Python packages from a custom PyPi. How can I write a Nix shell.nix to use those packages, alongside others which are in the standard PyPi?

Comment: You should probably write your own fetch function or the packages from the custom PyPi based on [`fetchPypi`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchpypi/default.nix)